# Trying to make two softbody spheres be connected

Tags: physics

I'm not entirely sure what I am asking for but I do know there probably is a term for it, if anyone knows the answer or could tell me what I am looking for that'd be great.

See, I want to take two soft body physics spheres and put one inside the other, and have it react when the bigger sphere collides with say- a floor, but not exactly the same amount. Both spheres will be clear, and the finished product will resemble a cell or amoebae. [image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what were the results? Does the inner sphere fall through the outer one?

Comment: Srry for the late response, I forgot to follow up on this one, but apparently parenting the smaller object to the bigger one doesn't work...

Comment: Should I remove soft body collision from the middle sphere or something? I think there is a way to have both be soft bodies and one be inside the other without issues but I can't figure out what.

Comment: To be honest, I don't play much with soft bodies, as I mainly do still images. I don't think I can solve this. I did play a little with it, and I have tried doing something similar but with rigid bodies in the past, but my results weren't satisfactory. When I asked for what you tried, I was mostly trying to encourage you to provide more information, so someone with more knowledge might take an interest.

Comment: Thank you anyway... It's the thought that counts.